# Add event listener to Excel Textbox (lose focus)

Tags: events, vba, excel, textbox

I need to fire an sub or a command when a user is done using a text box in Excel.

I have tried using the AfterUpdate() event and the LoseFocus() event like this:

```
Public Sub Kommentar_AfterUpdate()

MsgBox ("Hurray")

End Sub
```

The text box is named `Kommentar` and is inside the sheet `Radio`. Also, where is the code supposed to be written? i have tried placing it in code sheet for the Radio sheet, and in a separate module.

Any tip, hint or answer is appreciated!

Comment: What kind of Textbox are you using? If you use the ActiveX MS Forms 2.0 Textbox (Developer/Insert/ActiveX Controls/More Controls....) it has lots of events including `TextBox1_LostFocus()` and `TextBox1_Change()` which are the same as AfterUpdate() and the LoseFocus() .

Comment: I am using the normal text box added by inserting a text box through the normal ribbon in excel. Do i need to insert a special ActiveX text box through the developer ribbon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For embedded ActiveX Excel control - add the following in the sheet mobile in VBA. TextBox1 is the name of the control:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()


End Sub
```

For userform - use the following where Textbox1 is the name of your textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)


End Sub
```

You can set the Cancel bool to True if you do not want to lose focus from the textbox. In addition the code is placed within the UserForm >> Right Click >> View Code.

Comment: This is a text box in excel, not inside a userform. Is this code meant for a userform text box?

Comment: updated my answer and included embedded Excel controls. In VBA you can see in the event dropdown (top right) all available events for the control.

Comment: How is this the answer, the textbox is not an activeX control.

Comment: user added as an ActiveX control, this way you are not restricted to just the click event. For the avoidance of doubt I have updated my answer.